# Share a single SQL connection in multiple functions (without making it public)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a functions that calls method, and each method individually performs SQL connection task.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder ph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            SearchOrderID(true, 2, 3, 4, 8);  
            SearchOrderID(false, 2, 3, 4, 9);   
        }
    }
private void SearchOrderID(bool type,int Branch1ID, int Branch2ID, int Branch3ID, int DepartmentID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString1))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            ------code
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(findOrderID, cnn))
            {
                ------cod
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to use a single SQL connection, that shared among specific functions, without making it a public string (shared by all functions)?

Ideally i would want something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
          using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString1))
          {
            cnn.Open();
            ContentPlaceHolder ph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            SearchOrderID(true, 2, 3, 4, 8);  
            SearchOrderID(false, 2, 3, 4, 9);   
          }
        }
    }
private void SearchOrderID(bool type,int Branch1ID, int Branch2ID, int Branch3ID, int DepartmentID)
    {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(findOrderID, cnn))
            {
                ------cod
            }
        }
```

My primary objective it to increase performance, so the first thing came up was eliminate unnecessary task. Sharing 1 SQL connection is **theoretically FASTER** than multiple SQL connections, right?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Of course you can add a parameter `SqlConnection cnn` to method `SearchOrderID` -- What do you mean by "without making it public"?

Comment: ADO.NET has built-in [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) so any logical connection you make/share may in fact be mapped to the same physical connection

Comment: @Corak you can add cnn as paramter??? how please show me code or link please :(

Comment: @MickyD so you mean Code 1 and Code 2 are literally the same thing? that was very handy.

Comment: @Corak public means making SqlConnection as public string, that all functions can share. Some experts say its very risky and not recommanded.

Comment: Check "Pooling" parameter of [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8) it's true by default and makes code to reuse connections with same connection strings.

Comment: But if I understood description correctly, connection returns to pool only when you dispose or close it, so several simultaneously opened connections might end up with several physical connections. Never tested it myself.

Comment: _"are literally the same thing?"_ - yes, that's correct

Comment: `private void SearchOrderID(bool type,int Branch1ID, int Branch2ID, int Branch3ID, int DepartmentID, SqlConnection cnn)` <= see the last parameter? And then call it `SearchOrderID(true, 2, 3, 4, 8, cnn);` -- you could even have an overload of `SearchOrderID` without that parameter (as you have now) that would create and open the connection and then call the overload _with_ the parameter. -- But as others mentioned, that might not be as much of a performance boost as you might think. But the way to find out is to test in a realistic environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could make a function that stores your connection in a static variable. Something like this:

```cs
private SqlConnection ManageSQLConnection(bool disconnect = false)
{
    static SqlConnection conn = null;
    if (conn==null)
    {
        // Initialize your connection
    }
    if(disconnect)
    {
        // Dispose connection
    }
    return conn;
}

private void SearchOrderID()
{
    var conn = ManageSQLConnection();
    // Insert logic here
}
```

Don't forget to dispose the connection when disposing your class.